# PowerShell does not recognize the command Resolve-DnsName

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Error on power shell script,

```
Import-Module DnsClient
```

```
Import-Module : The specified module 'DnsClient' was not loaded because no
valid module file was found in any module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module DnsClient
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo : ResourceUnavailable: (DnsClient:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

```
Resolve-DnsName
```

```
Resolve-DnsName : The term 'Resolve-DnsName' is not recognized as the name of
a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Resolve-DnsName
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (Resolve-DnsName:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

[image]

```
PS C:\Users\aquib> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1
```

Comment: Don't post images with code... and add more details to the question!

Comment: @MohammadAquibAli please do not post important information in the comments, but in your question. They'll be much easier to read.

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. [Edit] the question to include addtional information, I did it only this time for you - so please delete your comments.

Comment: The error is *probably* because you don't have the `DnsClient` module installed.

Comment: How to add DnsClient in Windows Server 2008 r2

Comment: @MohammadAquibAli You don't.  The DnsClient module *does not exist* prior to Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Resolve-DnsName` is one of the commands added in Windows 8/Windows 2012 and later.  *By design*, it is not available on versions of Windows prior to that regardless of which version of PowerShell you use. The command is unavailable on Windows 7 and Windows 2008 R2 and earlier. Most sources I've read say that the underlying WinAPI functions that the command depends upon were added in Windows 8/2012.

I would recommend using `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($HostnameOrIP)` or [one of the other non-obsolete static methods in that class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns_methods(v=vs.110).aspx). However, that only works for A, AAAA, and PTR records, and there isn't a class in the .Net Framework CLR for generic DNS requests. You'd have to roll your own or use a third-party library like ARSoft.Tools.Net.

Comment: I try to execute this script for my AD users logon details, but Resolve-DnsName not work after skipping this workstation not display in report. This is the link for script -  https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-All-AD-Users-Logon-9e721a89

Comment: @MohammadAquibAli That script will not work on any version of Windows Server prior to Windows Server 2012.  It does not matter which version of PowerShell you have installed.  Microsoft created the DnsClient module after Windows Server 2008 R2's mainstream support window ended, so it's never available there *by design*.  The DnsClient is a feature added for Server 2012 and later.  You will need to upgrade your version of Windows Server to get access to the module.

Comment: I've logged on one of VM's in my company with Windows Server 2012 R2 and that function is missing. It's needed for `Test-NetConnection` command
Edit: it seems I need to put `Import-Module DNSClient` before executing something. I thought  it happens out-of-the box.